# Как в Java JPA сделать строгое обновление БД?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Если указать `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` в *application.properties* проекта, то БД будет обновляться, подстраиваясь под написанный код, но при этом оставляя старые свойства таблиц. К примеру если у таблицы *user* в БД есть *nullable* поле *name*, а в коде мы указали что поле **НЕ** должно быть *nullable*, то после запуска кода поле в БД так и останется *nullable*.

Все остальные режимы `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl` удаляют записи из базы данных, или наоборот, ничего не меняют.

Вопрос: можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы JPA изменяло нашу базу данных, четко соблюдая структуру, написанную в коде, и в то же время не удаляло записи из таблиц?

Comment: Чтоб совсем автоматически в общем случае не получится. Если вы поменяли поле с `nullable` на не `nullable` и без значения по умолчанию, то откуда JPA узнает, какие значения поставить существующим записям? Ответ - никак. Нужно писать миграцию данных вручную учитывая логику вашего приложения.

Comment: При чем тут JPA? Все режимы, за исключением `none`, можно использовать при разработке. Если у вас есть реальная бд, то надо писать скрипты. Перед запуском скриптов, желательно сделать бэкап существующей бд, но это уже вопрос к DBA.

Comment: Flyway, Liquibase - вам в помощь